# How to get data from null in month - laravel

Tags: laravel

I trying to get the data in mysql database, so i want to get all of the data even the date field is null, this is my code

```
$prod = DB::table('daily_enters')
                ->leftJoin('daily_inputs', 'daily_enters.daily_input_id', '=', 'daily_inputs.id')
                ->select('daily_inputs.date',DB::raw('sum(daily_enters.crops) as crops_actual'))
                ->whereIn('daily_inputs.date', $dates)
                ->where('daily_inputs.divisi', 'A')
                ->groupBy('daily_inputs.date','daily_inputs.divisi')
                ->get();
```

this the result

```
^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1403 ▼
  #items: array:30 [▼
    0 => {#1402 ▼
      +"date": "2022-01-02"
      +"crops_actual": 353.91
    }
    1 => {#1407 ▼
      +"date": "2022-01-03"
      +"crops_actual": 465.2
    }
    2 => {#1405 ▶}
    3 => {#1406 ▶}
    4 => {#1410 ▶}
    5 => {#1408 ▶}
    6 => {#1409 ▶}
    7 => {#1412 ▶}
    8 => {#1413 ▶}
    9 => {#1411 ▶}
    10 => {#1414 ▶}
    11 => {#1415 ▶}
    12 => {#1416 ▶}
    13 => {#1417 ▶}
    14 => {#1418 ▶}
    15 => {#1419 ▶}
    16 => {#1420 ▶}
    17 => {#1421 ▶}
    18 => {#1422 ▶}
    19 => {#1423 ▶}
    20 => {#1424 ▶}
    21 => {#1425 ▶}
    22 => {#1426 ▶}
    23 => {#1427 ▶}
    24 => {#1428 ▶}
    25 => {#1429 ▶}
    26 => {#1430 ▶}
    27 => {#1431 ▶}
    28 => {#1432 ▶}
    29 => {#1433 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

the data is return for 31 days in month but in 2022-01-01 is not found because its not have a data, but in this case i want to show the '2022-01-01' with data return = 0

so if you an any idea for this issue, please tell me the correct way for solve that issue. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the another way that i was trying

```
  $dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create($startDay, $endDay);
        foreach ($dateRange as $dt) {
            $dates[] = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
            $days[] = $dt->format('d');
        }
        $results = [];
        foreach ($dates as $date) {

            $prod_alls = DB::table('daily_enters_new')
                ->leftJoin('daily_inputs_new', 'daily_enters_new.daily_input_new_id', '=', 'daily_inputs_new.id')
                ->select('daily_inputs_new.sub_division', 'daily_inputs_new.date', DB::raw('sum(daily_enters_new.crops) as crops_actual'))
                ->whereDate('daily_inputs_new.date', $date)
                ->groupBy('daily_inputs_new.sub_division', 'daily_inputs_new.date')
                ->orderBy('daily_inputs_new.date', 'ASC')
                ->pluck('crops_actual');
            if ($prod_all) {
                $results[] = array($date => $prod_alls);
            } else {
                $results[] = array($date => 0);
            }
        }
```

This is the result

```
^ array:31 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "2023-01-01" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1477 ▼
      #items: []
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "2023-01-02" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1474 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => 372.27
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "2023-01-03" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1482 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => 370.67
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▶]
  4 => array:1 [▶]
  5 => array:1 [▶]
  6 => array:1 [▶]
  7 => array:1 [▶]
  8 => array:1 [▶]
  9 => array:1 [▶]
  10 => array:1 [▶]
  11 => array:1 [▶]
  12 => array:1 [▶]
  13 => array:1 [▶]
  14 => array:1 [▶]
  15 => array:1 [▶]
  16 => array:1 [▶]
  17 => array:1 [▶]
  18 => array:1 [▶]
  19 => array:1 [▶]
  20 => array:1 [▶]
  21 => array:1 [▶]
  22 => array:1 [▶]
  23 => array:1 [▶]
  24 => array:1 [▶]
  25 => array:1 [▶]
  26 => array:1 [▶]
  27 => array:1 [▶]
  28 => array:1 [▶]
  29 => array:1 [▶]
  30 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

this results that what i want, but the question is how to foreach that array into blade?

Answer (score 0):

I think best if you let laravel handle the date range, for example using

`$dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate)->toArray();`

And with the existing query, you get add `->get()->keyBy('daily_inputs.date');`

After that, just looping through $dateRange

```
foreach ($dateRange as $range) {
   $date = $range->format('Y-m-d');
   var_dump(isset($prod[$date]) ? $prod[$date] : null)
}
```

Hope this can help you.

NOTE:
as mention by @takumabo, you can also use laravel helper `data_get()`

```
$item = data_get($prod, $date);
var_dump($item ?? null)
```

and if daily_inputs.date type is datetime you can format it when used as key

```
->get()->keyBy(function ($record) { 
  return $record->date->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the result is return Illegal offset type

Comment: I apologize, I think I miss some code in my answer.
.. Please check it again ..

Comment: the return is Undefined array key "2022-01-01" sir

Comment: offset error is for what you can't find your correct error. so, please fix like this.

var_dump(isset($prod[$date]) ? $prod[$date] : null)
to
$item = data_get($prod,$date);
if (!item) var_dump(null);
var_dump($prod[$date]);

Comment: @takumabo thanks for you input, data_get is a laravel helper right? does data_get also accept wildcard ?

Comment: @LuthfiAnshari does daily_inputs.date a string type or datetime ? ... it will effect $prod list keys, please do note I use ->get()->keyBy('daily_inputs.date')

Comment: @Win happy new year bro ~♪ yes, dat_get() is laravel helper method. and also that method accept wild card. please see here, https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/en/helpers.html#method-data-get

Comment: @takumabo thanks and happy new year to you as well .. thanks for the link ... cool site, is it yours ?

Comment: @Win thanks, no, that site is created by volunteers for Japanese developers. sometime I read that site infos when I create by Laravel. here is official documentation for 9.x version. you can deeply lean this framework. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#main-content

Comment: Sorry for late discussion, thank u for your suggestion, i have already try that code but not working, now i try to find an another way to solve that